# How do I set yylval when using Flex and Bison in C++

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer, bisonc++

I am using Flex and Bison in C++. In the C version of both, yylval is a global union variable that stores information about the token.

In Bison C++, yylval is called semantic_type and it is a class member variable. How can I set the semantic information for the tokens from Flex C++? In Flex C++, the lexer is also a class and it does not have the semantic_type as a member variable.

I want to do something like this:

```
   ")"                          { return create_token(TOK_RPAREN, yytext, start_line, start_column);     }
"{"                          { return create_token(TOK_LBRACE, yytext, start_line, start_column);     }
"}"                          { return create_token(TOK_RBRACE, yytext, start_line, start_column);     }
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*         { return create_token(TOK_IDENTIFIER, yytext, start_line, start_column); }
[0-9]+                       { return create_token(TOK_NUM, yytext, start_line, start_column);        }
[ \t\n]+
","                          { return create_token(TOK_COMMA, yytext, start_line, start_column);       }
";"                          { return create_token(TOK_SEMICOLON, yytext, start_line, start_column);   }
.                            { yyerror("Unknown character: %c\n", yytext[0]); }

%%

void lexer_set_source_file(const char *filename) {
  g_srcfile = xstrdup(filename);
}

int CppLexer::create_token(yy::parseint tag, const char *lexeme, int line, int col) {
    struct SourceInfo info;
    info.filename = g_srcfile;
    info.line = line;
    info.col = col;
  
    if (tag == TOK_NUM) {
        nodeval.num_node = createNumberNode(lexeme, info);
    } else if (IsOperation(tag)) {
        nodeval.op_node = createOperationNode(tag, lexeme, info);
    } else if (tag == TOK_IDENTIFIER) {
        yylval.id_node = createIdentifierNode(lexeme, info);
    } else {
        nodeval.node = createCppNode(tag, lexeme, info);
    }
    
    return tag;
}")"                          { return create_token(TOK_RPAREN, yytext, start_line, start_column);     }
"{"                          { return create_token(TOK_LBRACE, yytext, start_line, start_column);     }
"}"                          { return create_token(TOK_RBRACE, yytext, start_line, start_column);     }
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*         { return create_token(TOK_IDENTIFIER, yytext, start_line, start_column); }
[0-9]+                       { return create_token(TOK_NUM, yytext, start_line, start_column);        }
[ \t\n]+
","                          { return create_token(TOK_COMMA, yytext, start_line, start_column);       }
";"                          { return create_token(TOK_SEMICOLON, yytext, start_line, start_column);   }
.                            { yyerror("Unknown character: %c\n", yytext[0]); }

%%

void lexer_set_source_file(const char *filename) {
  g_srcfile = xstrdup(filename);
}

int CppLexer::create_token(yy::parseint tag, const char *lexeme, int line, int col) {
    struct SourceInfo info;
    info.filename = g_srcfile;
    info.line = line;
    info.col = col;
  
    if (tag == TOK_NUM) {
        nodeval.num_node = createNumberNode(lexeme, info);
    } else if (IsOperation(tag)) {
        nodeval.op_node = createOperationNode(tag, lexeme, info);
    } else if (tag == TOK_IDENTIFIER) {
        yylval.id_node = createIdentifierNode(lexeme, info);
    } else {
        nodeval.node = createCppNode(tag, lexeme, info);
    }
    
    return tag;
}
```

Comment: I searched for `flex lexer c++ semantic_type` and found [this guide/example](http://www.jonathanbeard.io/tutorials/FlexBisonC++). Hope it helps.

Comment: Or you could look at the [C++ parser example in the bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#A-Complete-C_002b_002b-Example), which shows how to use "complete symbols" to produce something similar to the interface you want.